Code works but shows 401 client error in replit
I wrote this piece of code on my pycharm which works and still works anytime I run it on pycharm. But I needed to put the code on replit and it keeps giving me 401 client error on replit
On replit I had to put the keys in Environment variable using os modude
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from datetime import datetime
import os


APP_ID = os.environ['APP_ID']
API_KEY = os.environ['API_KEY']

URL = "https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/exercise"

SHEET_ENDPOINT = "https://api.sheety.co/87b10732a09117567a70b4341498006c/workoutTracking/workouts"

QUERY = input("Tell me what exercise you did: ")
GENDER = "female"
WEIGHT_KG = 72.5
HEIGHT_CM = 167.64
AGE = 30

headers = {
    "x-app-id": APP_ID,
    "x-app-key": API_KEY
}

parameters = {
    "query": QUERY,
    "gender": GENDER,
    "weight_kg": WEIGHT_KG,
    "height_cm": HEIGHT_CM,
    "age": AGE
}

response = requests.post(url=URL, json=parameters, headers=headers)
response.raise_for_status()
data = response.json()
print(data)

# step 4
exercise = data["exercises"][0]
today_date = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
now_time = datetime.now().strftime("%X")
INPUT = {
    "workout": {
        "date": today_date,
        "time": now_time,
        "exercise": exercise["name"].title(),
        "duration": exercise["duration_min"],
        "calories": exercise["nf_calories"]
    }
}

add_row = requests.post(url=SHEET_ENDPOINT, json=INPUT, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("username", "password"))
add_row.raise_for_status()
print(add_row.text)

It gave me this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Exercise-tracking/main.py", line 34, in <module>
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/home/runner/Exercise-tracking/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 1024, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/exercise


Hello. Try looking into the Nutritionix docs for this type of error. Check if Replit modifies any of your data or headers. Maybe you have an IP bind?

You may use url https://httpbin.org/post to send your POST request and it should send back all your headers and data - and you may run it on replit and on your computer and compare if both sends the same data. But sometimes portal like Nutritionix may block access from some servers because they can be used by spamers or hackers.
